# Variable not getting substituted when put under single quotes

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following script, how can I fill `$FIRST_NAME` value in `X`?

```
#!/bin/sh
FIRST_NAME='test'
X='{"firstname": $FIRST_NAME}'
echo $X
```

Comment: FIRST_NAME='test' ;  X=$(echo firstname:  $FIRST_NAME)
You can try this.

Comment: I did, may I know what's the reason?

Comment: `firstName='test'; final='{"firstname": "'"$firstName"'"}'; printf '%s\n' "$final"` is all you need.